# issues getting .NET service installed

Tags: .net, windows-services

I've been having on and off issues trying to get a service installed.

The problem is it installs fine on some machines, and others I either get that the service couldn't install
because of incorrect permissions, or that the service could be started, and these are all administrator account. I'm installing it using Advanced Installer.
What are some reasons that I could be having these issues? I should note the administrator account is a domain admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use the installutil.exe included with the .net framework version you are working with.  Installing with the utility will give you a log and tell you why the install may have failed.  In addition you will get prompted for a username and password if it is required during the installation process.  [The formal Microsoft docs are here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(VS.80).aspx)

Enjoy!

Comment: I do know about installutil, do you know if its possible to use it in a packaged install

Comment: Yes it is possible, as it runs as a console app...so you can just include it like any other 3rd party executable.